# How do I create log files inside my spring boot project directory?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-logback

How do I create log files inside my spring boot project directory? I want to create separate files for error and info messages. I'm using spring boot v. 2.5.

Comment: What have you tried? What are the problems you've encountered?

Comment: I've done this by using logback.xml. There, I've defined log files location as <Property name="logDirWindows">D:\\myLogs\\logger\\</Property>. However, I wanted to achieve this by giving the dynamic location (inside the project directory). Whenever applications started, it creates log files inside the project directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, add `log4j` dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

then create a `log4j.xml` file in your project directory with the following cinfig:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN" monitorInterval="30">
<Properties>
    <Property name="LOG_PATTERN">%highlight{%d -%r-%-5p %X{MdcHeader} %C{1.} - %m%n}{STYLE=Logback}</Property>

    <!--WINDOWS LOG DIRECTORY-->
    <Property name="logDirWindows">D:\\myLogs\\logger\\</Property>
    <Property name="logDir">${logDirLinux}</Property>
</Properties>
<Appenders>
    <Console name="ConsoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT" follow="true">
        <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}"/>
    </Console>

    <RollingRandomAccessFile name="MainLogger" fileName="${logDir}main.log" filePattern="${logDir}main.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}" bufferedIO="true" >
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
        </Policies>
        <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}"/>
    </RollingRandomAccessFile>

</Appenders>


<Loggers>
    <Logger name="MainLogger" level="info" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="MainLogger"/>
    </Logger>
    <Root level="info">
        <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

as you can see in the config file, I define a directory address to store the log:

> ```
> <Property name="logDirWindows">D:\\myLogs\\logger\\</Property>
> ```

Comment: It has some additional configs that maybe not necessary.

Comment: As mentioned in the question that I want to create log files in the project directory only.

Comment: @Waseem then change this `D:\\myLogs\\logger\\` directory to your project directory.

Comment: Is there not any dynamic way to create?

Comment: what do you exactly mean by not dynamic?

Comment: Actually, I want to create dynamically. Not by passing the directory name in the XML file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237092/discussion-between-waseem-and-mr1554).